# Change javascript dynamically on EventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a context menu that opens on touch & causes, that users are not able to pan on a modal in order to show all the content of a modal.

Thus, I would like to disable the menu when a modal is opened & enable the menu on closing the modal again. Therefore, I use bootstrap event listeners.

```
const modalmenutrigger = document.getElementById('modal-40');
//when modal-40 is shown disable menu
modalmenutrigger.addEventListener('show.bs.modal', event => {
  // do som         
      var my_menu = 0;
});
//when modal-40 is hidden enable menu
modalmenutrigger.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', event => {
  // do som
      var my_menu = new ContextMenu;
});
```

This does not really work. It enables the menu after showing & hiding modal-40. However, when showing & hiding modal-40 again the menu does not work anymore. Also it in not possible to pan the modal, when the modal is shown the 2nd time.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show some HTML Markups, and try to reporduce the issue on the code snippet

Comment: Thanks, I will try. However, in general it should work as described above?